# getting song details from other class

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get data from array list method.I have created a class

```
public class SongDto {

public long songId;
public String songTitle;
public String songArtist;
public String path;
public short genre;
public long duration;
public String album;
public Bitmap albumArt;

public String toString() {
return String.format("songId: %d, Title: %s, Artist: %s, Path: %s, Genere: %d, Duration %s",
        songId, songTitle, songArtist, path, genre, duration);
}
```

and getting these value in another class name

```
public class Utils {
private Context _context;

// constructor
public Utils(Context context) {
    this._context = context;
}
public static ArrayList<SongDto> getMusicInfos(Context context) {

    ArrayList<SongDto> musicInfos = new ArrayList<SongDto>();
```

and now I am trying to get the the songTitle in another class

```
private ArrayList<SongDto> musicInfos;
private Utils utils;
private ArrayList<String> songPaths = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    utils = new Utils(this);
    songPaths = utils. getMusicInfos(songTitle);
}

private void update(){
    ArrayAdapter<String> list=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,musicInfos.add(songTitle) );
}
}
```

How I can get only the desired array like array of songId ,songArtist,song duration.And where I am doing wrong .How to set the getMusicInfos method

Answer (score 0):

For example I want to get arrays of titles from arrays of SongDto, using apache collection utils :

```
Collection<String> songTitles = CollectionUtils.collect(songDtos, new Transformer()  
  {  
    public Object transform(Object o)  
    {  
      String s = ((SongDto) o).title;  
       return s;
    }  
  });
```

And ofcourse you can convert the collection to array.

Comment: they are practically non existent. :-P

Comment: getting error in collectionUtils and transformer method! how to fix this any ex